# ggplot: why does legend prints for both geom_ribbon and geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have

[image]

Why does the plot print double legends?

I have

```
ggplot(res, aes(time, P)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = CIF), alpha = 0.15, show.legend = F) +
  geom_line(aes(color = CIF, linetype=CIF)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,60)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "grey30"), name="") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "grey30"), name="")
```

I would like two different `linetypes` - the solid and dotted.

I tried adding `show.legend = F` to `geom_ribbon()`. I also tried `scale_linetype_manual(values=c("twodash", "solid"))`, but that did not work either.

Thanks.

```
res <- structure(list(CIF = c("CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=SSTR", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", "CIF0 1; treatment=Control", 
"CIF0 1; treatment=Control"), P = c(0.0126582278481013, 0.0379746835443038, 
0.0886075949367089, 0.227848101265823, 0.291139240506329, 0.30379746835443, 
0.382612849295438, 0.382612849295438, 0.396034309093364, 0.396034309093364, 
0.396034309093364, 0.464778371472981, 0.479335937623958, 0.493893503774936, 
0.493893503774936, 0.493893503774936, 0.511964965203736, 0.530857856697482, 
0.551739473611621, 0.551739473611621, 0.551739473611621, 0.587770498875235, 
0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15, 
0.15, 0.175, 0.2, 0.225, 0.25, 0.275, 0.3, 0.325, 0.35, 0.375, 
0.4, 0.425, 0.45, 0.478333333333333, 0.506666666666667, 0.535, 
0.565909090909091, 0.596818181818182, 0.631590909090909, 0.666363636363636, 
0.701136363636364, 0.735909090909091, 0.770681818181818, 0.805454545454545, 
0.840227272727273), time = c(0.1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.7, 8, 8.9, 
9.7, 12, 13, 13.8, 15.6, 16, 21, 22, 26.2, 32, 57, 75.9, 0.23, 
0.26, 0.49, 0.53, 0.69, 3.15, 3.25, 4.5, 5.12, 5.78, 6.67, 7.65, 
7.79, 7.85, 9, 9.99, 11.37, 12.68, 13.11, 15.05, 15.83, 16.89, 
18.17, 22.7, 23.59, 29.6, 32.65, 35.81, 43, 43.79, 45.37, 46.45, 
46.65, 69.02, 105.16), var = c(0.000158202495137301, 0.000462438062709035, 
0.00102223150704103, 0.00222700435462509, 0.00261236940688262, 
0.00267727299463126, 0.00302351549629627, 0.00302351549629627, 
0.00306970677553502, 0.00306970677553502, 0.00306970677553502, 
0.00324806886701391, 0.00327981948633184, 0.00330477943336831, 
0.00330477943336831, 0.00330477943336831, 0.00338725054763293, 
0.00347160443129604, 0.00358270141371878, 0.00358270141371878, 
0.00358270141371878, 0.00419942239566404, 0.000609375, 0.000609375, 
0.000609375, 0.000609375, 0.000609375, 0.0011875, 0.001734375, 
0.00225, 0.002734375, 0.0031875, 0.0031875, 0.003609375, 0.004, 
0.004359375, 0.0046875, 0.004984375, 0.00525, 0.005484375, 0.0056875, 
0.005859375, 0.006, 0.006109375, 0.0061875, 0.00632641203703703, 
0.00641259259259259, 0.00644604166666666, 0.00649476818807913, 
0.00646626455672426, 0.00645943933132982, 0.00632128240045078, 
0.00605179376408715, 0.00565097342223891, 0.00511882137490608, 
0.00445533762208865, 0.00366052216378662), lower = c(0.00179283085601356, 
0.012407758030848, 0.0432569770133707, 0.150156366547099, 0.204034730694035, 
0.215087827961636, 0.285234141005005, 0.285234141005005, 0.297424496991439, 
0.297424496991439, 0.297424496991439, 0.36086454355377, 0.37440719657064, 
0.388052792532856, 0.388052792532856, 0.388052792532856, 0.404225382627521, 
0.421151881064098, 0.439577758163688, 0.439577758163688, 0.439577758163688, 
0.465233551748622, 0.00355981698627006, 0.00355981698627006, 
0.00355981698627006, 0.00355981698627006, 0.00355981698627006, 
0.0127444761396915, 0.0248237564000704, 0.0387548083597935, 0.0540289278928447, 
0.0703518337133965, 0.0703518337133965, 0.0875349177801499, 0.105448804967606, 
0.124000413393049, 0.143120415258911, 0.162755851975246, 0.182865529959695, 
0.20341701986178, 0.22438463188234, 0.245748013164318, 0.267491158005832, 
0.289601702577961, 0.312070423267255, 0.337084153386502, 0.362632734261147, 
0.388713550110491, 0.417009262625303, 0.446060748331539, 0.478344299849033, 
0.511927776545623, 0.546903575783177, 0.583428286459313, 0.621755981338108, 
0.662308487815083, 0.705837515898454), upper = c(0.0864676146914305, 
0.113119926557592, 0.17689479704179, 0.336970740219573, 0.404797292536867, 
0.418088438924316, 0.499724044921284, 0.499724044921284, 0.513377498673078, 
0.513377498673078, 0.513377498673078, 0.582237375808006, 0.596712789588013, 
0.61106223186708, 0.61106223186708, 0.61106223186708, 0.629786201841186, 
0.649274218414355, 0.671039700993493, 0.671039700993493, 0.671039700993493, 
0.71481943223174, 0.164514540888494, 0.164514540888494, 0.164514540888494, 
0.164514540888494, 0.164514540888494, 0.185453879855473, 0.214782436042548, 
0.244858945502003, 0.274592902916402, 0.303763783420835, 0.303763783420835, 
0.332343773644891, 0.360355238540763, 0.387832132523894, 0.414808316400823, 
0.441314057995926, 0.467375240079267, 0.493013472868414, 0.518246474164134, 
0.543088485840094, 0.56755064509021, 0.591641285440807, 0.615366163389952, 
0.642996938577391, 0.669919078034907, 0.696160621236471, 0.724897048548371, 
0.752630120302531, 0.78395657751485, 0.813600779732339, 0.841596636148257, 
0.867931528334935, 0.892542509012415, 0.91530398695896, 0.935999137248638
), n.risk = c(79, 78, 76, 72, 61, 56, 53, 46, 45, 44, 43, 41, 
34, 33, 29, 28, 24, 22, 19, 17, 12, 9, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 
34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 
18, 15, 14, 13, 11, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2), n.event = c(1, 
2, 4, 11, 5, 1, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-57L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. To combine legends they need to have identical names. You weren't removing the name of linetype's aes.

```
 ggplot(res, aes(time, P)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = CIF),alpha = 0.15) +
  geom_line(aes(color = CIF, linetype=CIF)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,60)) +     
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "grey30")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "grey30"))
```

If you want no legend name, you need to add `scale_linetype(name = "")` and change the name for the other aes to "".

```
ggplot(res, aes(time, P)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = CIF),alpha = 0.15) +
  geom_line(aes(color = CIF, linetype=CIF)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,60)) +
  scale_linetype(name="") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "",values=c("black", "grey30")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("black", "grey30"))
```

If you set ribbon show.legend to F it will not represent the darkness of the fills.

Comment: I think you can just take out all the `name =`s too and it'll work

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks to you both.

Comment: Adding `scale_linetype(name="")` changes it back to two legends. Where should I specify the `name=""` to get rid off the "CIF"-name printed above the legends without creating two legends again?

Comment: I would just remove the name argument from all aes, per alistaire's suggestion, if you want to have them, you need to make sure they are all exactly the same, i'll add to my answer with an example